# Examples for Globals

Tags: craft-features, globals

I just check the CMS. It looks great.

One question about the Globals: Where could they be used?

I found them in a Navigation-Example. Do you have other examples for me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's the beauty of Globals... they can be used anywhere!

Common usage examples include (but not limited to):

- Content in your header
- Content in your footer
- Content in your sidebar
- Anything else that appears frequently in your website

It's not a strict rule, but Globals tend to work great in situations where you only need a small amount of content to be commonly repeated throughout your site.